# ionic 3 after installed app on mobile splash after white screen for long time ? how i can solve this?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

> I'm creating an app in ionic 3
>
> after installed in mobile showing a white screen for a long time why?
>
> how I can solve this...

[Config.xml](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IC1_Pkq7ldCdb_vl_n4PxUMwRKXIAoMs) here

[Package.json](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aWeeU9se2jAb-UhzTRd5uJAoynVsZ5nY)

[image]

Comment: did you check this with production build apk....? because in my case production build takes less time to load

Comment: actually i think that was error ...

Comment: how i will find that error...

Comment: Just follow this documentation: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging

Comment: is there any others ways to find this error....

Comment: Are you doing any api calls in your root component ?

Comment: i called api's in  pages

Comment: i put some alert msg in app.component page 

that was showing 

but root page alert was not showing just white screen (all time)

Comment: i got error while Remote debug  ===>>>
deviceready did not fire within 5000ms. This can happen when plugins are in an inconsistent state. Try removing plugins from plugins/ and reinstalling them.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of long `SplashScreenDelay` time.

Replace

```
 <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="22000" />
```

with

<`preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="2000" />`

Comment: You can inspect the app using Google Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Try Updating your main.ts file as below

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import {enableProdMode} from "@angular/core";

enableProdMode();
platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

and build your app with --prod flag